# Tor wants to launch cmd.exe each time it starts or exit

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am currently using Sandboxie and I get an alert from Sandboxie that Tor wants to launch cmd.exe each time Tor starts or exit.

Currently using version 3.5 of Tor Browser Bundle.

What does Tor do with cmd.exe and should I allow Tor to use cmd.exe?

Comment: Please include the version number instead of just "latest version". Later readers will have no idea what version this may have applied to after subsequent releases.

Answer (score 1):

This is Windows console window, it appears on every console application and there is nothing to worry about.

Possibly Tor needs to run some additional terminal commands.

To avoid it you should start Tor programmatically passing the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag to CreateProcess(). 
Or use a special tool like hstart.

Alternatively create file "start.vbs":

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run """Path to your Tor executable""", 0, False
```

And start it with:

```
wscript.exe "PATHTO:\start.vbs"
```

Source:

- http://torforum.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=18312